# Reclassifying and vectorizing specifc classes in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, reclassify, polygonize

My raster file has 29 classes and I applied 'Reclassify by table' in QGIS 3.16 to assign 1 to classes 15 and 24 only and all other classes were classified as 0.
I applied the following script to polygonize these two classes which works fine without the reclassify part.

```
 var image = ee.Image("users/parivash89/verceli_tiles_3")
      .toInt();
 var oldgroup = ee.List([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]);
 var newgroup = ee.List([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]);

    Map.addLayer(newgroup );
    Map.centerObject(newgroup );
    
    var classes = newgroup .reduceToVectors({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.countEvery(), 
      scale: 10,
      maxPixels: 1e10
    });
    
    var result = ee.FeatureCollection(classes);
    
    Map.addLayer(result);
    
    // Export the FeatureCollection to a SHP file.
    Export.table.toDrive({
      collection: result,
      folder: 'GEE_Polygonize',
      description:'Vercelli_tiles_3',
      fileFormat: 'SHP'
    });
```

But when I add the reclasify part, I get this error:

```
Cannot add an object of type <List> to the map.
    in <global>, line 67
    in <global>, line 83
```

What should I add to choose the selected classes only and polygonize only them?

Comment: Please provide complete example which reproduces the error you mention. As of now, `newgroup` is not defined.

Comment: Thanks @kkrao, I thought I defined it by indicating the var newgroup. Maybe that is my error. I changed the code as I run it in the question

Comment: I am still unable to reproduce your error. Please share the image asset (make it public). The current error is: 
Image (Error)
Image.load: Image asset 'users/parivash89/verceli_tiles_3' not found.

Comment: Thanks @kkrao. I realized what was my mistake. I add my answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remap function was my answer since I was tring to operate on individual values. By adding these lines, the script was done:

```
.remap([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29],
       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]);
```